# How exactly did the prisoners escape the Jem'hadar prisoner camp?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-transporter, star-trek-dominion, jemhadar

DS9 "By Inferno's Light":

> MARTOK: He wired the message and the transmission coordinates directly
>   into the system circuitry. That way all he had to do was connect the
>   transmitter to the power grid and let it run.
>
> WORF: Could the coordinates and the message be changed?
>
> GARAK: **You're planning to contact the runabout.**
>
> WORF: **We could activate the transporter and beam ourselves onto the
>   ship.**
>
> BASHIR: And run like hell.

And then a bit later in the episode:

> GARAK: Doctor, would you keep the noise down? I'm trying to work in
>   here.
>
> BASHIR [OC]: Garak, how many translator circuits have you got left?
>
> [Barracks]
>
> GARAK [OC]: Three.
>
> BASHIR: Well, work fast, because pretty soon we're going to be up to
>   our necks in Jem'Hadar.

Next scene:

> KAT'IKA: I yield. I cannot defeat this Klingon. All I can do is kill
>   him, and that no longer holds my interest.
>
> DEYOS: Shoot them both.
>
> [Crawlspace]
>
> GARAK: Got it.
>
> [Internment centre]
>
> (Just as Ikat'ika is killed, our **heroes are beamed out**.)

I loved the episode but was really confused by this aspect of it.

I don't understand how they escaped. They do not have communicators on. I assume there's gotta be some kind of shielding around the prison. There's a runabout floating in space close enough to transport that's unattended. Garek is being asked to send a coded message of some sort to the runabout to transport more people out then transported down, without communicators attached to them, in different areas.

What kind of message did Garek send to affect that kind of transport? How did a runabout sit close enough to the prison to be in transporter range, but not be detected? How did they flee Dominion space in a runabout without getting chased down after the transport?

Comment: As for the range, I think one of them said something about that during the episode

Comment: The runabout was left in orbit by the Jem Hadar because they didn't consider it a threat and just left it there - after all it wasn't hurting them and was of little concern.

Comment: Because the dominion dropped the idiot ball- leaving a warp capable craft only a short distance from a prison camp? Dr. Evil from the Austin Powers movies wouldn't have made that mistake!

Answer (score 5):

At that point the only prisoners left were our heroes, as the Breen and the Romulan died, and the Cardassians had been released (other than Garrak).  The transport command could have been a short program to lock-on and transport all non-Gamma quadrant races (since the sensors can differentiate) to the runabout, which was within the prison's defensive perimeter (for plot reasons, and I suppose to show Dominion arrogance). As you said, they didn't have communicators, so transporting by species was their only option not to also grab the guards.